# Spliting String and storing in sparate variable in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to Split following trying string `address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID`

```
$a[1] =     address:message:ID
$a[2] =     address:message:ID
$a[3] =   address:message:ID
$a[4] =   address:message:ID
$a[5] =    address:message:ID
$a[6] =    address:message:ID
```

Again i want to split above string i'm trying to split in following

```
$a[1][1] = address 
$a[1][2] = message
$a[1][3] = ID
```

How i can perform this operation without losing the speed of code execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `foreach` and to loop through the exploded string using `|` as the delimiter , Pass those exploded values to another `explode()` using the `:` as the delimiter and push them in a new array `$new_arr` using `array_push`

```
<?php
$str='address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID';
$new_arr=array();
foreach(explode('|',$str) as $k=>$v)
{
  array_push($new_arr,explode(':',$v));
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/I7Xmg2)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this using `Explode` and `foreach`

```
<?php
      $str='address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID|address:message:ID';
$arr=explode('|',$str);
foreach($arr as $v){
 $a[]=explode(':',$v);
        }
 print_r($a);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/135258)</kbd>

**output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => address
            [1] => message
            [2] => ID
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => address
            [1] => message
            [2] => ID
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => address
            [1] => message
            [2] => ID
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => address
            [1] => message
            [2] => ID
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => address
            [1] => message
            [2] => ID
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => address
            [1] => message
            [2] => ID
        )

)
```